# Ubuntu Budgie system tray icon overlap

Tags: system-tray, budgie, ubuntu-budgie

I have installed Ubuntu Budgie recently and I'm facing this problem every time I turn system on and some times It can solve by restarting system (Not always). Can any body help to fix this issue?
[image: This is how It looks]

Comment: Report bugs here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntubudgie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It will be solve if you restart budgie-panel. You can also add command to startup.

Answer (score 0):

This bug made me very upset.

The solution I've found was to restart the budgie panel, however, I should do this at every login.

In order to do that, I added the following command to my ~/.profile file:

```
sleep 15 && nohup budgie-panel --replace &
```

The sleep is needed because if we restart the panel before it loads the solution will not work (maybe you should increase or decrease the sleep time to be the best fit for your machine).